# context deadline exceeded: pushing logs to Loki via Promtail

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I am trying to integrare Log4j logs generated by a Java app to a Loki instance, exposed via a Grafana cloud. I have done the following:

1. Create a Grafana Cloud Subscription
2. Create a Loki data source for logs (Verified the data source using the test options)
3. Installed a local instance of promtail (v 2.8.4) on my Windows laptop, and configured to read the logs from a local folder.

Upon starting promtail, I see that the logs are correctly polled, but are not being posted to Loki. I see an error

```
 level=warn ts=2023-09-04T05:02:01.7894344Z caller=client.go:419 component=client host=logs-prod-006.grafana.net msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 tenant= error="Post \"https://<<user id>>:***@logs-prod-006.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push\": context deadline exceeded"
```

All the solutions available in Internet seem to indicate a Network problem, but I have been able to successfully hit the Loki endpoint via Postman.

Here is the promtail config

```
 server:
  http_listen_port: 0
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: https://<<user id:password>>@logs-prod-006.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: log/*.log
```

Here is a sample of the log

```
2023-09-04 09:50:12.414  INFO 1 --- [istener-1-0-C-1] .s.s.e.b.m.c.EventBrokerTemplateListener : Received message on outbound topic: from-mdsvc-sap-cic-plant-plant. internalUUID: 936bf1fa40813742254a980080dc345c, subaccountId: 093981df-e9e6-44f3-9515-d8e633a9e4ab
2023-09-04 09:50:12.787  INFO 1 --- [istener-1-0-C-1] c.s.s.e.b.m.api.eb.MessagePublisher      : Successfully invoked the Event Broker Publisher. EndpointUrl: https://<<Some Url>>, Message Id: [936bf1fa40813742254a980080dc345c], Response Code: 202 ACCEPTED
```

I have been to execute this request successfully

```
curl --location 'https://<<user-id:password>>@logs-prod-006.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data 'JSON Payload'
```

Any inputs on the error that I am facing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Prabal